# Replace duplicates in-place (Excel or Google Sheets)

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets, microsoft-excel-365

Is there in-built functionality to remove duplicates in-place in Excel (365) or Google Sheets across several columns? For example, consider this set of data:

[image: Original data]

The goal is to select the entire data range (or the entire 1st, 2nd and 3rd columns) and blank out duplicates in the 1st column only. Entire rows with duplicates should not be deleted. The required result should look like this:

[image: Data required]

Both applications have options which appear to apply:

- Excel: `Data > Remove Duplicates`
- Google Sheets: `Data > Data clean-up > Remove duplicates`

But both operate in the same way => Rows with duplicate data are deleted:

[image: Data in Excel or Google Sheets]

Comment: There is no such built-in tool (not often used, usually the reverse operation is required - to fill empty cells with previous values). Usually a formula like `=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:A2,$A2)=1,$A2,"")` starting from the second row in the auxiliary column, fill down, cut and paste as a value over the original range is sufficient. It's not much harder than choosing "Remove Duplicates" from the menu.

Comment: Important question: WHY do you want to do that? If it is just for presentation purposes, then a simpler solution would be to apply conditional formatting to the first column to hide any values that are the same as the row above (eg set number format to ;;; )

Comment: @AdamV: I'm appending to an ongoing spreadsheet with data exported from a database (on roughly a weekly basis). To easily find the next insertion point this functionality would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Pivot table of your data. Set the Layout as Tabular Form (do not repeat item labels), do not show grand or subtotals. This would be easy to refresh if your data are a table.

Then (optionally) if you want, you could copy the pivot table and paste elsewhere as special values.

[image]